# Sending data to server via UDP

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, sockets, udp, uwp

I'm trying to use Raspberry Pi and a 7" touchscreen to create an Assetto Corsa dashboard, coding with vb on the Universal Windows Platform.

I'm experiencing A LOT of problems with this platform because objects are very different from .net and I find the Microsoft's logic very strange.

However, I try to explain the problem: Assetto Corsa have his own telemetry that when the user starts a session begins to send some data to the connected clients on port 9996, UDP Protocol.
Really, the game is not so simple because to "bind" a client to the server there is a "procedure" that consists in:

- The client have to send a structured data containing 3 ints ("110")
- The server responds sending to the client some data containing the
  track name, the player name and others
- The client must send another structured data, this time containing
  "111" After this, client and server are "handshaked" and the server
  start sending continuous data to the client containing a lot of data
  concerning the car's physics.

Here is a more accurate description of the handshaking protocol: [Assetto corsa UDP Telemetry documentation](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KfkZiIluXZ6mMhLWfDX1qAGbvhGRC3ZUzjVIt5FQpp4/pub)

Since those are the first time that I approach UPD communication, I would have been sure to have correctly understood how it works, so I wrote this python script:

```
from socket import *
from struct import *

serverName='127.0.0.1'
serverPort = 9996
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)
message=pack('iii',1,1,0)

clientSocket.sendto(message, (serverName, serverPort))

messageback, ipAddress=clientSocket.recvfrom(1024)
print 'received'
pktformat='408c'
n = calcsize(pktformat)
print n
#n = len(messageback)
#print n

backString = unpack(pktformat, messageback)
#print backString[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
#print "fffffff"
message=pack('iii',1,1,1)
clientSocket.sendto(message, (serverName, serverPort))

i=0
while 1:
    pktformat='4chfff??????fffhhhhfffffhf4f4f4f4f4f4f4f4f4f4f4f4f4f4fff5f'

    messageback, ipAddress =clientSocket.recvfrom(16384)
    n = calcsize(pktformat)
    print n
    n = len(messageback)
    print n
    backString = unpack(pktformat, messageback)
    print backString
    i+=1

clientSocket.close()
```

Everything works but Python GUIs are not so good to see so I would move to VS+VB+UWP+WIN10IoT.

```
Dim s As String = "110"
        Dim byteCommand As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s)


        Dim writer As New DataWriter(listener.OutputStream)
        writer.WriteBytes(byteCommand)

        Try
            Await listener.ConnectAsync(hostname, "9996")
            Await writer.StoreAsync()



        Catch ex As Exception
            testo = ex.Message
            refreshTb()
        End Try
```

With this code I'm able to receive THE FIRST communication from server, so I repeat the code sending "111":

```
Private Async Sub HandShake(inStream As IBuffer)
        If handShaked Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        handShaked = True
        Dim writer As New DataWriter(listener.OutputStream)


        Dim s As String = "111"
        Dim byteCommand As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s)
        writer.WriteBytes(byteCommand)

        Await writer.StoreAsync()
        testo = "hand-shaked!"

    End Sub
```

After this, nothing happens.

I tried:
 1. Send data as string, instead of byte(). Nothing changed
 2. Send "XXX" instead of "110": I expected to not receive nothing but I received the same as when I send "110"!!!

So I'm starting to think that the I'm not correctly converting "110" so I'm sending a kind of data to server that it's not able to understand.

Any ideas?

Comment: No one? :desperate:

Comment: Please add the description of what the 'listener' is in your code.